# Convert Bitmap with any pixel format to specific pixel format

Tags: delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to convert a bunch of images with could have pixel formats of anything (4bit, 8bit, 16bit, 24bit etc) to an image that is 1bit.

I have the following code which will convert 24bit to 1bit, but this doesn't handle any other pixel formats.

```
procedure TFormMain.ButtonConvertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  NewBitmap: TBitmap;
  x,y: Integer;
  ScanLine: pRGBTriple;
  Colour: Integer;
  FilePath: String;
  FileName: String;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(EditFileName.Text);
    NewBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      NewBitmap.PixelFormat := pf1bit;
      NewBitmap.Height := Bitmap.Height;
      NewBitmap.Width := Bitmap.Width;
      for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height -1 do
        begin
          ScanLine := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
          for x := 0 to Bitmap.Width -1 do
            begin
              Colour := (ScanLine.rgbtBlue + ScanLine.rgbtGreen + ScanLine.rgbtRed) div 3;
              if (Colour >= 128)
                then Colour := clWhite
                else Colour := clBlack;
              NewBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := Colour;
              Inc(ScanLine);
            end;
        end;
      FilePath := ExtractFilePath(EditFileName.Text);
      FileName := TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(EditFileName.Text);
      NewBitmap.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(FilePath, FileName + '-copy.bmp'));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(NewBitmap);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Bitmap);
  end;
end;
```

I could handle each case individually, but there seems like there should be a function that does this. I have looked into the TGPBitmap.Clone function class, but I could only get it to produce blank(white) images and was unable to find any examples of its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way - draw any bitmap on 24bit one and use existing code.

The slowest way - get color of every pixel through Pixels[] property

Otherwise you have to treat every kind of bitmap individually. Note that 1,4 and 8-bit bitmaps contain indexes of palette, so you need to get proper color from bitmap palette, and 15 and 16-bit bitmaps pixels have structure xRRRRRGGGGGBBBBB and RRRRRGGGGGGBBBBB, so you need to extract 5 and 6-bit color parts and calculate overall pixel luminance.

Comment: The top line is sufficient for me - so simple I should have thought of it.